# set limits to numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have two arrays with some data. In particular, the y array contains percentages that can not exceed y = 100 value.
The y values satisfy the condition y <100 but if I make a fit, the result is that the curve exceeds y = 100, as shown in the figure below.

Is there any way to make a curve fit that does not exceed y = 100?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

x = [0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75,2.15,2.75,3.15,3.75,4.15,4.75,5.15,5.75]
y = [ 100.,100.,90.,69.23076923,47.36842105,39.13043478,   
     35.71428571,26.31578947,22.22222222,18.86792453,
     11.76470588,9.43396226]

coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 3)
ffit = poly.polyval(x, coefs)
plt.plot(x, ffit)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be a fit?  How about an interpolation?

Comment: The short answer is no. In general, curve fitting tries to find the parameters of a continuous function that most closely "fits" the given data. Something like a maximum value doesn't make sense mathematically. The best you could do is scale your output so it falls within your desired range, or do some sort of clipping, ie `ffit = np.clip(poly.polyval(x, coefs), a_min=0, a_max=100)`. Or perhaps use an exponential.

Comment: This clipping suggestion is the only way to be certain. The data also fits a simple scaled power law rather well, "y = a * b^x" with a =  1.4738762808541190E+02, b =  6.2972002084332779E-01 so long as you clip.

Comment: thanks @pault, that is what I need!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `polyfit` function a list of degrees that you want to fit, which means that you can leave out certain degrees (for example the constant value). With a bit of manipulation you can get what you want.

Assuming that you want your fit function to reach 100 at your minimum x value (0.25), you can subtract that 100 from all y-values, subtract 0.25 from all x values and then fit a polynomial such that only the coefficients for the first, second and third degree terms are fit parameters, but not the zeroth (or constant) term. Then, after the fitting you can set that constant term to 100 and compute the new, fitted values. I adjusted your example code to illustrate what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.array([0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75,2.15,2.75,3.15,3.75,4.15,4.75,5.15,5.75])
y = np.array([ 100.,100.,90.,69.23076923,47.36842105,39.13043478,   
     35.71428571,26.31578947,22.22222222,18.86792453,
     11.76470588,9.43396226])

x_new = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1], 100)

##the original way to fit
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 3)
ffit = poly.polyval(x_new, coefs)

##the adjusted way to fit
coefs2 = poly.polyfit(x-0.25, y-100, [1,2,3])
coefs2[0] = 100
ffit2 = poly.polyval(x_new-0.25,coefs2)

ax.plot(x_new, ffit, label = 'without constraints')
ax.plot(x_new, ffit2, label = 'with constraints')
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro', label = 'data')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data look rather like a Boltzmann sigmoid than a polynomial function to me. By saying that I don't want to imply it is a sigmoid function - the OP knows, what the data represent. I don't.

Comment: @Piinthesky probably, but the OP asked for a polynomial.

Comment: Was only a hint for the OP to re-evaluate, if a polynomial function is the right descriptor for the data set. Nothing to do with your approach. Your graph only made this so prominent.